# Centered images are blurry

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I' have a lot of png's with different sizes, and i want to load them into a table. I have this code:

```
charImage.image = [self imageForId:g.charId glyphNr:g.glyphNr];
[charImage sizeToFit];
//charImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
charImage.center = CGPointMake(30, 23);
```

Everything works fine except that my pngs are blurry. If i don't center them, are extremely sharp. They are all made from curves. I didn't exported them all, so is still a chance to export with a fixed size and the drawings already centered, but i want to know if i'm doing something wrong or incomplete. Why are they blurry?

I think is not possible to upload any photo here..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will make sure the frame is at integer coordinates:

```
int centerX = 30;
int centerY = 23;
CGSize size = charImage.frame.size;
charImage.frame = CGRectMake((int)(centerX - size.width / 2),
                             (int)(centerY - size.height / 2),
                             size.width, size.height);
```

The difference between this and

```
charImage.center = CGPointMake(30, 23);
```

is that the `.center` setter could set the origin to a non-integer point when either of the width or height is of the wrong parity.  As other people have said here, images and text look blurry when they're at non-integer coordinates.

Comment: Note that this thing also happens when your image size is not "even" in either height or width (eg 301x199 size). In that case, using UIViewContentModeCenter may blur your image even without using center.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the pngs get placed at sub-pixel positions. Using sizeToFit together with UIViewContentModeCenter makes this happen. When you don't use UIViewContentModeCenter, the views are placed at (0.0, 0.0), and hence do not blur.

If you want to avoid blur, first don't use sizeToFit, then use this to center the image:

```
image.frame = CGRectMake(round(centerX - image.frame.size.width / 2.0),
                         round(centerY - image.frame.size.height / 2.0),
                         image.frame.size.width,
                         image.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: As i understand the sizeToFit makes my UIImageView to take the size of the UIImage, so the contentMode here has no effect, that's why i commented it. i couldn't handle the scalings of the UIImageView so i prefered to center directly the UIImageView. charImage is a UIImageView

Comment: You are right: you don't need to set the content mode. But if you sizeToFit, the image might get stretched, and that in itself can of course make the image appear blurry. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

you might use calculated coordinates instead of contentMode:

`charImage.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)`

Comment: can you help me calculate some fixed values? this is equivalent with the center property but they're still not fixed values, i don't know how, the bounds are 46x46px:

charImage.frame = CGRectMake((46-[charImage bounds].size.width)/2, (46-[charImage bounds].size.height)/2, [charImage bounds].size.width, [charImage bounds].size.height);

Comment: I think it's ok to change only the position, not to calculate a new frame, isn't it? But not sure what's the property.